# What are the effects on vision, of the breakdown of vitreous humour in eyes with age?

Tags: eye, age

What would be the effects on the vision in an eye due to the breaking down of the eye's vitreous humour due to age? Going beyond just floater appearing, is there any effect on the optical characteristics of the now liquified humour?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?